# Do I need to link my existing app to Admob if I'm working on a new version?

Tags: flutter, admob

I have an existing app (without ads) published on Google Play Store. Now, I'm working on a new version with more features (and incorporating ads). So while adding the app to Admob, should I link the existing previous version app in Playstore or should I give 'App not published' ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should link the existing version of the app. I understand your confusion is because there are no ads in the existing app. But since it is published, there is nothing wrong in linking Admob to it as eventually you are going to submit the new version to the same app on Playstore.

Comment: yeah, I did that and it's been more than 5 days - I'm only able to see test ads. Real ads aren't shown. So I thought that maybe linking the existing version was the problem. Any clue on how long will it take? or where should I approach if this issue prolongs.

Comment: @Santhoshivan "I'm only able to see test ads. Real ads aren't shown."
Do you mean you are seeing test ads in the live app?

Comment: No, in the new version which isn't published

Comment: That is as it should be. We are not supposed to see real ads in an app which is not published yet. In other words, in development environment. In fact, never use real Ad IDs during development. That is against the policies. Your Ad IDs could even be blocked if you use them during development. Always use test Ad IDs for that. As long as you have submitted the app with real IDs in it, you should see the real ads in the live version once it is published.